# Using `sourceCpp` to compile `fastLm`

Tags: r, rcpp

I started playing around with `Rcpp` and would like to use the `fastLm` function as an example (also because it's useful for potential later work). I know that `fastLm` is part of the `RcppArmadillo` package but I would like to compile it using `sourceCpp`. The code can be found [here](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.armadillo.html) and is also below.
The first problem I encounter is that I can't simply run `sourceCpp("fastLm.cpp")` in R after installing and loading `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo`. I get this error `error: RcppArmadillo.h: No such file or directory` and then all kind of things, which I guess follow from that.

The second issue is that I think I need to change some stuff in the `fastLm.cpp`. My changes are also below but I am sure something is missing or wrong. I included `#include <Rcpp.h>` and `using namespace Rcpp;` and `// [[Rcpp::export]]` to export the function to R and I changed the arguments from `SEXP` to `NumericVector` and `NumericMatrix`. I don't see why that shouldn't work and a similar adjustment is probably possible for the return value?

**fastLm.cpp**

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

extern "C" SEXP fastLm(SEXP ys, SEXP Xs) {

    Rcpp::NumericVector yr(ys);                 // creates Rcpp vector from SEXP
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix Xr(Xs);                 // creates Rcpp matrix from SEXP
    int n = Xr.nrow(), k = Xr.ncol();

    arma::mat X(Xr.begin(), n, k, false);       // reuses memory and avoids extra copy
    arma::colvec y(yr.begin(), yr.size(), false);

    arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);      // fit model y ~ X
    arma::colvec resid = y - X*coef;            // residuals

    double sig2 = arma::as_scalar( arma::trans(resid)*resid/(n-k) );
                                                // std.error of estimate
    arma::colvec stderrest = arma::sqrt( sig2 * arma::diagvec( arma::inv(arma::trans(X)*X)) );

    return Rcpp::List::create(
        Rcpp::Named("coefficients") = coef,
        Rcpp::Named("stderr")       = stderrest
    ) ;

}
```

**fastLm.cpp changed**

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
extern "C" SEXP fastLm(NumericVector yr, NumericMatrix Xr) {

    int n = Xr.nrow(), k = Xr.ncol();

    arma::mat X(Xr.begin(), n, k, false);       // reuses memory and avoids extra copy
    arma::colvec y(yr.begin(), yr.size(), false);

    arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);      // fit model y ~ X
    arma::colvec resid = y - X*coef;            // residuals

    double sig2 = arma::as_scalar( arma::trans(resid)*resid/(n-k) );
                                                // std.error of estimate
    arma::colvec stderrest = arma::sqrt( sig2 * arma::diagvec( arma::inv(arma::trans(X)*X)) );

    return Rcpp::List::create(
        Rcpp::Named("coefficients") = coef,
        Rcpp::Named("stderr")       = stderrest
    ) ;

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to indicate dependency on `RcppArmadillo` with the `Rcpp::depends` pseudo attribute. This will take care of finding `RcppArmadillo` headers and link against `blas`,  `lapack` etc ...

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List fastLm(NumericVector yr, NumericMatrix Xr) {

    int n = Xr.nrow(), k = Xr.ncol();

    arma::mat X(Xr.begin(), n, k, false);       // reuses memory and avoids extra copy
    arma::colvec y(yr.begin(), yr.size(), false);

    arma::colvec coef = arma::solve(X, y);      // fit model y ~ X
    arma::colvec resid = y - X*coef;            // residuals

    double sig2 = arma::as_scalar( arma::trans(resid)*resid/(n-k) );
                                                // std.error of estimate
    arma::colvec stderrest = arma::sqrt( sig2 * arma::diagvec( arma::inv(arma::trans(X)*X)) );

    return Rcpp::List::create(
        Rcpp::Named("coefficients") = coef,
        Rcpp::Named("stderr")       = stderrest
    ) ;

}
```

Also, it is very important that you use `#include <RcppArmadillo.h>` and not `#include <Rcpp.h>`. `RcppArmadillo.h` takes care of including `Rcpp.h` **at the right time**, and order of include files is very important here.

Also, you can return a `List` and drop the `extern "C"`.

Comment: Nice. The only thing is missing now is the try/catch block which the OP's example also omitted (but which is in the src).